# mysql fulltext search как сделать поиск по одному слову?

Tags: mysql

здравствуйте, у меня есть небольшая функция поиска

```
MATCH (" . $field . ") AGAINST ('" . addslashes(str_replace(array('(', ')'), null, $txt)) . "*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

но дело в том что такой поиск выдает меньший результат по одному слову, нежели к примеру `LIKE '%слово%'`
так вот суть вопроса заключается в том, как можно сделать так чтобы FTS поиск возвращал такой же менее чувствительный результат как LIKE?